# How to test our model in mlr3 with nested hyperparameter optimization

Tags: mlr3

I have just started learning mlr3 and have read the mlr3 book (parameters optimization).
In the book, they provided an example for the nested hyperparameters but I do not know how to provide the final prediction i.e. predict (model, test data). The following code provides learner, task, inner resampling (holdout), outer-resampling (3-fold CV), and grid search for tuning. My questions are:

```
(1) Dont we need to train the optimized model i.e. at in this case like train(at, task) ?

(2) After train, how to predict the data with test data as I am not seeing any splits of train and test data?

The code taken from mlr3 book (https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/nested-resampling.html) is as follows:  

library("mlr3tuning")
task = tsk("iris")
learner = lrn("classif.rpart")
resampling = rsmp("holdout")
measure = msr("classif.ce")
param_set = paradox::ParamSet$new(
  params = list(paradox::ParamDbl$new("cp", lower = 0.001, upper = 0.1)))
terminator = trm("evals", n_evals = 5)
tuner = tnr("grid_search", resolution = 10)

at = AutoTuner$new(learner, resampling, measure = measure,
  param_set, terminator, tuner = tuner)

rr = resample(task = task, learner = at, resampling = resampling_outer)
```

Comment: This is the common "CV vs train/predict" misunderstanding. I'll probably write a blog post soon about this to avoid repeating myself over and over in such questions :)

Comment: @pat-s, I will wait for your post but could u plz respond to my question here briefly? I am confused at this point and unable to proceed.

Comment: Do some research about what cross-validation is meant for and what it returns (and how it differs to a 'normal' train/predict. There is plenty of material out there :) Also search a bit on https://stats.stackexchange.com/. That's all I can say in two sentences for now.

Comment: @pat-s, thank you for your suggestion. I have used them in R language (not mlr3). First we used to divide the data into train and test, then performed CV with train data and train the model. Then performed the prediction with test data. I have just a confusion in mlr3. In the mlr3 gallery German credit example, they have divided the data into train and test set but when they were using the hyperparameters optimization in the same tutorial, they did not divide the data into train/test as the code I provided above.

Comment: The code you're using is splitting the data into different train and test sets multiple times, each time evaluating the performance of the model and making decisions with respect to the best hyperparameters based on that. You should see information on the observed performance while running your code.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, Ok so no need to explicitly split the data into train and test sets?

Comment: That's correct. Unless you want to evaluate in a very specific way that you define yourself.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff thanks again for your comments. But just a confusion raises in my mind. Would it be unbiased if we use train (full iris dataset) and predict(full iris dataset). I am sorry but I came from caret library background, so it feels like strange to me..

Comment: `mlr3` does the splitting into train and test based on the resampling method you provide. It doesn't train and test on the same data unless you tell it to.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, ok I got your point.. Thanks a lot. I read in the book that we can specifiy the train/test ratio in the resampling i.e. rsmp("holdout", ratio = 0.8)

Comment: data=read.csv("results.csv")

task=TaskRegr$new("data", data, target = "Results") learner= lrn("regr.rpart")  resampling = rsmp("holdout")
measure = msr("regr.mae")

search_space = ParamSet$new(
  params = list(ParamDbl$new("cp", lower = 0.001, upper = 0.1)))

terminator = trm("evals", n_evals = 5)
tuner = tnr("grid_search", resolution = 10)

Comment: at = AutoTuner$new(
  learner = learner,
  resampling = resampling,
  measure = measure,
  search_space = search_space,
  terminator = terminator,
  tuner = tuner
) resampling_outer = rsmp("cv", folds = 10)
rr = resample(task = task, learner = at, resampling = resampling_outer)

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, is the above code the correct way to optimize the parameters?

Comment: Looks technically correct to me, but I would use random search and a much larger number of evaluations.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, thanks for your feedback.. I know that larger number of evaluations would be more better, but why not grid search?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, after we use the benchmark (), how we can get the individual performance (for all the the folds of CV) of the tuned and untuned learner? grid = benchmark_grid(
  task = task,
  learner = list(at, lrn("regr.rpart")),
  resampling = rsmp("cv", folds = 10)
)
bmr = benchmark(grid)

Comment: Grid search is usually inefficient. And see https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/benchmarking.html

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, thanks a lot again.. I have read this benchmarking... I want to perform the wilcoxon test for the performance estimates (i.e. MAE values) obtained with the tuned learner and with the untuned learner. How can I obtain the MAE values of all the folds of tuned and untuned learners. For instance, wilcox.test (MAE with tuned, MAE with untuned).

Comment: See 2.6.4 in the benchmarking chapter.

Comment: Ok thank you @LarsKotthoff.. I am going to check this section.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, though I did not find the section 2.6.4 very helpful but I have used the following code to extract the MAE values of the tuned learner and untuned learner. First three MAE values are of one learner and the other three MAE values are of another learner. The code is here and it gives me the p values.    
                                resampRF=bmr$score(msr("regr.mae"))[1:3,11]
                                resampRPART= bmr$score(msr("regr.mae"))[4:6,11]
                                wilcox.test(resampRF$regr.mae, resampRPART$regr.mae, pair=T)

Comment: I used random search to tune params of RF, how to find the optimal value of the 'mtry' parameter? at = AutoTuner$new(
  learner = learner,
  resampling = resampling,
  measure = measure,
  search_space = search_space,
  terminator = terminator,
  tuner = tuner 
) resamplingouter = rsmp("cv", folds = 5) grid = benchmark_grid(task = task, learner = list(at, lrn("regr.rpart")),resamplingouter)
bmr = benchmark(grid)